# MS Access form; Two procedure cause a "conflict"

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form in Access with a Submit button to add a record to my table. The code is the following:

```
Private Sub SaveRecord_Click()
  If (IsNull(Description)) Then
     Beep
     MsgBox "The Description Field is empty. Please add a description.", vbCritical
  ElseIf (IsNull(Category)) Then
    Beep
    MsgBox "The Category Field is empty. Please add a Category.", vbCritical
  Else
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
  End If

  Forms!frm_DataEntry!dataEntry_subform.Requery
End Sub
```

I also have a Before_Update Event for the form to ask the user if they want to submit a record that have not been submitted. See code below.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
 If Me.Dirty Then
   If MsgBox("The current record have not been saved. Do you want to save?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Save Record") = vbNo Then
     Me.Undo
   End If
End If

Exit_BeforeUpdate:
 Exit Sub

Err_BeforeUpdate:
 MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
 Resume Exit_BeforeUpdate

End Sub
```

I have tried modifying the code and using other events but I am not able to accomplish the following:
1. If I click Submit button I do not want the user to see a message window asking if they want to save the record. How can I hide this message? It is possible to set the form's Dirty to False right before saving (line DoCmd.RunCommand asCmdSaveRecord). I tried using Me.Dirty=False but it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA to prevent empty fields in a user-entry form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854654/vba-to-prevent-empty-fields-in-a-user-entry-form)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new boolean variable. Set it to true, if true exit before message box displays.

```
blnDoNotShowMessage = True
If blnDoNotShowMessage Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```