# VBA to prevent empty fields in a user-entry form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am having trouble with VBA coding which I am using to check for blank fields in a pop-up form. The code is supposed to check for blank fields on the form, notify the user if there are blank forms, and if there isn't, add the record. I have a second function which saves the record, then closes the form. Below is the code I am using to check for blanks:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Dim ctrl As Control
Dim strMsg As String

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls

    If ctrl.Tag = "BlkChk" Then
        If IsNull(ctrl) Then
           strMsg = strMsg & "- " & ctrl.Name & vbCrLf
        End If
    End If

Next ctrl

If strMsg <> "" Then
    If vbOK = MsgBox("The following fields require a response:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
       strMsg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf, _
       vbOKOnly) Then
       Cancel = True

       Me.cboLookup.SetFocus
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Here is the code for my 'add record' button:

```
Private Sub cmdAddRecord_Click()
On Error GoTo cmdAddRecord_Click_Err

    DoCmd.Save
    DoCmd.Close , ""

cmdAddRecord_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmdAddRecord_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume cmdAddRecord_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

The first bit of code works fine, but when I click my 'add record' button, and execute my second bit of code, it will notify the user twice, then close the form without saving, regardless if all blanks are filled in or not. I've went through several examples online about how other people have set it up to see if I could implement their ideas, but it's just not working for me. I think it might have something to do with the 'add record' code, but I can't seem to figure it out. How should I approach this problem? should I restructure my coding or should I combine it all into a single On_Click() command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the `MsgBox()` method correctly.  Try this:

```
If strMsg <> "" Then
   MsgBox "The following fields require a response:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
       strMsg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbOKOnly

   Me.cboLookup.SetFocus
   Cancel = True

End If
```

Comment: Hmm, it's still kicking me off the form without saving it. It will show me which fields require a response, and once I click 'OK' it will show me again. Clicking 'OK' a second time kicks me off the form. Will my 'add record' code override my BeforeUpdate code and just continue to close the form?

Comment: What if you disable the "Add Record" button and let the form set the record as designed (save upon closing form or moving to another record)? At least for testing. Does everything work better?

Comment: That actually works a little better! I disabled the control box initially so it wouldn't confuse the user, and replaced it with a custom 'close button' that informs the record has been changed in some way and asks the user if they want to save it or not. However, just using the actual close box to exit informs the user that the record cannot be saved at this time and prompts for a yes/no to exit anyways. This basically achieves what both my custom buttons are supposed to do. 

Thanks Smandoli, this helps me out a lot!

Comment: Woot! You can probably finesse the close event as well. Make a private function that handles the validation and returns `True` or `False`, and then call that function from different form events so the helpful warning is raised consistently. Sorry I can't offer more details but I wasn't able to rough out that code with a sense of confidence just now.

Comment: That is an excellent idea, I'll see it I can implement it! Thanks again :)

Comment: Extra hint:  Make sure the validation function handles as much as possible, including raising the message box and setting the field focus.  One can usually fulfill the Do-It-Once principle with a happy sense of satisfaction.

Comment: I will definitely keep that in mind. I have a feeling I am going to have to restructure a few things from what I've learned today. If anything it will give me something to do tonight.